# Justify an unbiased estimator is UMVUE

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid $N(\theta,\theta)$, with $\theta\in(0,\infty)$. Is $\bar{X}$ the UMVUE (beta unbiased estimator) of $\theta$?

I find the complete sufficient statistic is $T=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2$. So $\bar{X}$ is not a function $T$. Then we cannot justify it is UMVUE or not. Can someone help me here?

How to get complete sufficient statistis?
$\frac{f(x\mid\theta)}{f(y\mid\theta)}=\exp(\frac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i^2-x_i^2)+\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i))$. Let $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$.

My work

I got $\log L(x\mid\theta) = -\frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{\theta} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{2} \frac{1}{\theta^2}-\frac{n}{2}$. Then, I let $\frac{\partial \log (x\mid\theta)}{\partial \theta}=0$. Then, I have $-\frac{n}{2}\theta^2-\frac{n}{2}\theta+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=0$. Then, I find the solution is weird. Am I wrong?

Comment: can you write down the steps you followed to obtain $T$. Intuitively one can expect that the variance of $T$ needs to be less than both the sample mean or sample variance estimator.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören. Can you tell me more?

Comment: find the likelihood function then take the logarithm and then find the maximum with respect to the parameter. Write them down in your question as EDIT or ADDED or My work. Then I will tell you more.

Comment: I havent checked if you derived correclty but if so, then you end up with the roots of a second order polinomial. It seems that the roots must be real because the last term in your equation is positive, i.e. multiply all terms by $-2/n$ and check again. Another thing is that the root is a function of $T$, the last term of you polinomial after normalization by $-2/n$. This suggests, but not proves that $T$ is indeed a sufficient statistic.

Comment: If $T$ is a complete sufficient statistic and $\bar X$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$, then the conditional expected value of $\bar X$ given $T$ is the UMVUE for $\theta$. That's what the Lehmann–Scheffé theorem tells us about this situation. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Do you mean $\bar{X}$ is not UMVUE since it is not a function of $T$?

Comment: That would follow, but I am not yet persuaded that the statistic you've identified is the minimal sufficient statistic.  I'll take a look at the details. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy. Should every UMVUE be a function of sufficient statistic?

Comment: In principe, a function of every sufficient statistic can be UMVUE. However, It is not sufficient. There are MLEs (a function of the sufficient statistic) which are not UMVUE. The problem is that in such a case it is non-trivial to say if there exists indeed which is UMVUE. My best guess is that UMVUE, if it exists should be a function of sufficient statistic.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören : Some MLEs are not sufficient statistics and most MLEs are biased. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy possible. Biased mles can be corrected for the bias and will eventually become unbiased. The question is if there are mles which are not sufficient statistic but they are umvue. I don't believe that there exist such.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören : What do you mean by saying biased MLEs can be corrected for bias?    If you "correct" an MLE for bias, it's no longer an MLE. And in some cases no unbiased estimator exists.  For example, suppose $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots\sim\mathrm{i.i.d.} \, \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)$ and you observe only $X_{2n-1}\times X_{2n}$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. Then no unbiased estimator of $p$ exists, but an MLE exists.  And sometimes all unbiased estimators are far worse than the biased MLE, as in this example: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206006.pdf ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Maybe by "eventually" you meant "asymptotically"? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy sorry I have a limited inet access. Yes I meant that. For example $X_1,X_2,...\sim \mathrm{i.i.d\,\, Uniform(0},\theta)$, $\hat{\theta}=\max \{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$. This is MLE and the correction is done by multiplying $\hat{\theta}$ by $(n+1)/n$. The latter estimator is UMVUE. It is not MLE but just scaled version of it with some function of the sample size.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören : But your statement that all biased MLEs can be so corrected is wrong. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I didn't say all. I said that there is also such an option and if so...

Answer (score 1):

$\bar X$ is the UMVUE for $\theta$. In fact, you haven't expressed the minimal sufficient statistic correctly.

The following result will make this clear:

**Theorem**: Given simple random sample from a population $X$ with density of the form

$$f_\theta(x)=c(\theta)h(x)e^{\sum_{j=1}^{p}q_j(\theta)T_j(x)}$$

where the functions $q_j(\theta)$ and $T_j(x)$ are such that there are no linear combinations of them so that it could be possible to simplify the exponent, then the statistic

$$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}T_1(X_i), \sum_{i=1}^{n}T_2(X_i),...,\sum_{i=1}^{n}T_p(X_i)\bigg)$$

Is a minimal sufficient statistic for the given population

If in this case we have $X\sim N(\theta,\theta)$, the density of the population is

$$f_\theta(x)=\frac{1}{\theta\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{2\theta^2}}\quad,\quad x\in \mathbb{R},\ \theta>0$$

So we can give the following factorization

$$f_\theta(x)=\frac{1}{\theta\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\theta^2}+\frac{x}{\theta}}\quad,\quad x\in\mathbb{R},\ \theta>0$$

making the follwing identifications:

$$c(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}} \ , \ h(x)=1 \ , \ q_1(\theta)=-\frac{1}{2\theta^2} \ , \ q_2(\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta}, T_1(x)=x^2 \ , \ T_2(x)=x$$

And applying the previous theorem, gives us that the minimal sufficient statistic for this distribution is

$$T=\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2,\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\bigg)$$

Of course, we can't simplify the exponent further, as the vectors from $T$ are linearly independent.

We would like to check as well that this is a complete statistic, but there is no need to verify that is satisfies the definition, as the following result states:

**Theorem**: In the same conditions of the previous theorem, the statistic

$$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}T_1(X_i), \sum_{i=1}^{n}T_2(X_i),...,\sum_{i=1}^{n}T_p(X_i)\bigg)$$

is complete if the image of the function $(q_1(\theta),q_2(\theta),...,q_n(\theta))$ contains an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$

(see E.L. Lehmann "Testing Statistical Hypothesis", Springer Texts in Statistics, 1986)

It is clear that the function $q(\theta)=(q_1(\theta),q_2(\theta))=\big(\frac{-1}{2\theta^2},\frac{1}{\theta}\big)$ contains some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for $\theta>0$, so we conclude from the previous theorem that the statistic $T$ is minimal, sufficient and complete.

To conclude that $\bar X$ is the UMVUE for $\theta$, note that

$$T^\star=\big(\bar X, s^2\big)$$

Is another minimal sufficient and complete statistic, and also

$$E_\theta[\bar X]=\theta\qquad,\quad\theta>0 $$

So we conclude from the Lehmann-Scheffé theorem that $\bar X$ is the UMVUE for $\theta$ as it is the only unbiased estimator for $\theta$ that is function of $T^\star$

Comment: To see a proof - using the definition - that in a normal population the statistic $\big(\bar X, s^2 \big)$ is complete, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2741439/351735

Comment: Could you explain why would't it be the UMVUE? I don't see the flaw of my reasoning

Comment: I would, sometime later. I had been searching for some online material and I found [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/315812123_On_sequential_estimation_of_a_normal_distribution_having_equal_mean_and_variance/fulltext/58eba1de0f7e9b6b274b92b5/315812123_On_sequential_estimation_of_a_normal_distribution_having_equal_mean_and_variance.pdf?origin=publication_detail) paper relevant.

Comment: Okay, this is indeed a one-parameter exponential family (not what I claimed before) but the complete sufficient statistic is simply $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$. I would ask you to redo your calculation and check this with me.

Comment: Clearly, $\bar X$, though unbiased for $\theta$, is not a function of the complete sufficient statistic. As such, it cannot be the UMVUE.

Answer (score 1):

We have a random sample $(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ drawn from $\mathcal N(\theta,\theta)$ population where $\theta>0$.

Joint density of $(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ is

\begin{align}
f_{\theta}(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)&=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\theta\pi}}\exp\left[-\frac{(x_i-\theta)^2}{2\theta}\right]
\\&=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^n{\theta}^{\,n/2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\theta)^2\right]
\\&=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^n{\theta}^{\,n/2}}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\frac{n\theta}{2}\right]
\\&=\exp\left[-n\ln \sqrt{2\pi}-\frac{n}{2}\theta-\frac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\frac{n\theta}{2}\right]
\\&=\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-n(\theta+\ln\sqrt{2\pi})+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right],\quad(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n\,,\,\theta>0
\end{align}

As such, $\mathcal N(\theta,\theta)\in\text{One parameter exponential family}$ and hence $\displaystyle T(\mathbf X)=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$. The OP found this correctly.

Since $E(X_1)=\theta$, UMVUE of $\theta$ would be $E\left(X_1\mid\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\right)$ by the Lehmann-Scheffe theorem. Or we can say that $E(\bar X\mid \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2)$ is the UMVUE as $\bar X$ is also unbiased for $\theta$. Both would give the same UMVUE as UMVUE is unique whenever it exists.

> So we can be certain that $\bar X$ is **not** the UMVUE of $\theta$ as we do not expect the conditional expectation $E(\bar X\mid T)$ or $E(X_1\mid T)$ to simply equal $\bar X$. Moreover, in this case, $\bar X$ is not a function of the complete sufficient statistic $T$, so we can rule out the possibility of it being the UMVUE.

---

For the actual UMVUE, one can refer to [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/315812123_On_sequential_estimation_of_a_normal_distribution_having_equal_mean_and_variance/fulltext/58eba1de0f7e9b6b274b92b5/315812123_On_sequential_estimation_of_a_normal_distribution_having_equal_mean_and_variance.pdf?origin=publication_detail) paper by S. Nadarajah. He had simplified the expression of the UMVUE found previously by Mukhopadhyay/Cicconetti in [their](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/SQA-200039002) paper.

According to Nadarajah, UMVUE of $\theta$ is

$$T^*(\mathbf X)=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}{n}}\frac{I_{n/2}\left(\sqrt{n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}\right)}{I_{n/2-1}\left(\sqrt{n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}\right)}$$

,where $I_m(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind of order $m$.

Other equivalent expressions for the UMVUE are also presented by the author.